# codeIgniter error: Undefined property

Tags: php, codeigniter

A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Magazine::$db
>
> Filename: core/Model.php
>
> Line Number: 52

---

```
<?php

    class MY_Model extends CI_Model {
        const DB_TABLE = 'abstract';
        const DB_TABLE_PK = 'abstract';


        function __construct(){
            parent::__construct(); // construct the Model class
        }
        /**
         * Create record.
         */
        private function insert() {
            $this->db->insert($this::DB_TABLE, $this);
            $this->{$this::DB_TABLE_PK} = $this->db->insert_id();
        }

        /**
         * Update record.
         */
        private function update() {
            $this->db->update($this::DB_TABLE, $this, $this::DB_TABLE_PK);
        }

        /**
         * Populate from an array or standard class.
         * @param mixed $row
         */
        public function populate($row) {
            foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
                $this->$key = $value;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Load from the database.
         * @param int $id
         */
        public function load($id) {
            $query = $this->db->get_where($this::DB_TABLE, array(
                $this::DB_TABLE_PK => $id,
            ));
            $this->populate($query->row());
        }

        /**
         * Delete the current record.
         */
        public function delete() {
            $this->db->delete($this::DB_TABLE, array(
               $this::DB_TABLE_PK => $this->{$this::DB_TABLE_PK}, 
            ));
            unset($this->{$this::DB_TABLE_PK});
        }

        /**
         * Save the record.
         */
        public function save() {
            if (isset($this->{$this::DB_TABLE_PK})) {
                $this->update();
            }
            else {
                $this->insert();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Get an array of Models with an optional limit, offset.
         * 
         * @param int $limit Optional.
         * @param int $offset Optional; if set, requires $limit.
         * @return array Models populated by database, keyed by PK.
         */
        public function get($limit = 0, $offset = 0) {
            if ($limit) {
                $query = $this->db->get($this::DB_TABLE, $limit, $offset);
            }
            else {
                $query = $this->db->get($this::DB_TABLE);
            }
            $ret_val = array();
            $class = get_class($this);
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $model = new $class;
                $model->populate($row);
                $ret_val[$row->{$this::DB_TABLE_PK}] = $model;
            }
            return $ret_val;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

---

and my controller is the next one

---

```
<?php
if ( ! defined("BASEPATH") ) exit("No direct script access allowed");

class Magazine extends CI_Controller {

 public function index(){

     $this->load->model('Publication');
     $this->Publication->publication_name = 'Sandy Shore';
     $this->Publication->save();
     echo '<tt><pre>' .  var_export( $this->Publication, TRUE) . '</pre></tt>';

     $this->load->model('Issue');
     $issue = new Issue();
     $issue->publication_id = $this->Publication->publication_id;
     $issue->issue_number=2;
     $issue->issue_date_publication = date('2015-04-21');
     $issue->save();
     echo '<tt><pre>' .  var_export( $issue, TRUE) . '</pre></tt>';

     $this->load->view('magazines');   
 }    


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please make sure you have this line of code in your config/autoload.php file?

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

These two are the most common libraries required throughout the project.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your time, right now appear new error, im doing something grong again 







A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\Codelgniter\system\database\DB_driver.php
Line Number: 125

Comment: You should check if you have proper database configuration in config/database.php file. I.e. the host, username, password, db name etc.

Comment: Really Thankyou for your time, im trying with CodeIngniter im totally new, on this. and is funny but hard.


My new error shows the next legend, but i asume is about configuration things


------

Comment: An Error Was Encountered

In order to use the Session class you are required to set an encryption key in your config file.

Comment: You should really go through the Codeigniter user guide first to avoid this kind of basic configuration issues. Regarding your question, codeigniter session needs a security key to encrypt the cookie content. You can find it under application/config/config.php and find `$config['encryption_key']`. There you need to put some arbitrary alphanumeric values of length 32.

Comment: Thankyou Su Much, you have deep knowladge on this, youare to great, thankyou once, again :D :D :D